# ¿Cómo obtengo un dato de un usuario específico de la base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos, users-roles

Tengo la conexión a la base de datos mediante PDO, por lo que no pude utilizar las formas de consulta mediante variables a la base de datos porque no sé como combinarlos y estoy intentando mostrar el dato "permisos" según el usuario que esté logueado. El usuario pude obtenerlo a través de este código:

```
class User extends DB{ /*db es base de datos*/
    private $nombre;
    private $username;

    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $query = $this->connect()->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE username = :user');
        $query->execute(['user' => $user]);
    
        foreach ($query as $currentUser){
            $this->nombre = $currentUser['nombre'];
        }
    }

    public function getNombre(){
        return $this->nombre;
    }
}
```

Pero cuando hago lo mismo para obtener el permiso, tengo los errores:

> Undefined variable $permisos

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getPermiso() on null.

Esto es lo que estaba intentando:

```
class Permisos extends DB{
    private $permisoActual;


    public function setPermiso($permiso){
        $query = $this->connect()->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE permisos := :permiso');
        $query->execute(['permisos' => $permiso]);

        foreach ($query as $currentPermiso){
            $this->permisoActual = $currentPermiso['permiso'];
        }
    }

    public function getPermiso(){
        return $this->permisoActual;
    }
```

Para luego mostrarlo en el index de php de esta manera:

```
<span>Bienvenid@,</span> <?php echo $user->getNombre();
                                  echo $permisos->getPermiso();?>
```

Cómo puedo obtener el dato guardado en la columna permiso de la base de datos según el usuario que haya iniciado sesión?

Comment: Error tipográfico, porque el marcador está en singular `:permiso` y el arreglo en plural `['permisos' => $permiso]` ambos deben ser iguales. Por otra parte, creo que te complicas haciendo más consultas de las necesarias, porque puedes guardar toda la información del usuario en sesión o una propiedad privada de la clase y parece que podrías obtener permisos que no correspondan al usuario actual.

Comment: Aparte de lo comentado, aquí ```echo $permisos->getPermiso();``` quieres obtener el valor del permiso, pero no creo que va funcionar, 1. no veo que primero llamas a tu ```function setPermiso($permiso)``` para crear el valor de ```$this->permisoActual``` que es la quieres obtener en tu **echo**.